# Dynamically create ranges from numeric sequences

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, numeric-ranges

I have a table like the following:

```
+----+-----+-----+
| ID | GRP | NR  |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 | 1   | 101 |
|  2 | 1   | 102 |
|  3 | 1   | 103 |
|  4 | 1   | 105 |
|  5 | 1-2 | 106 |
|  6 | 1-2 | 109 |
|  7 | 1-2 | 110 |
|  8 | 2   | 201 |
|  9 | 2   | 202 |
| 10 | 3   | 300 |
| 11 | 3   | 350 |
| 12 | 3   | 351 |
| 13 | 3   | 352 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

I wanted to create a view which groups this list by `GRP` and concatenates values in `NR`.
Is it possible to dynamically detect sequences and shorten them into ranges? 
Like `1, 2, 3, 5` would become `1-3, 5`.

So the result should look like this:

```
+-----+--------------------+
| GRP |        NRS         |
+-----+--------------------+
| 1   | 101 - 103, 105     |
| 1-2 | 106, 109 - 110     |
| 2   | 201 - 202          |
| 3   | 300, 350 - 352     |
+-----+--------------------+
```

What i got now is simply concatenate values, so the table above would become this:

```
+-----+--------------------+
| GRP |        NRS         |
+-----+--------------------+
| 1   | 101, 102, 103, 105 |
| 1-2 | 106, 109, 110      |
| 2   | 201, 202           |
| 3   | 300, 350, 351, 352 |
+-----+--------------------+
```

Here's the actual statement:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , GRP VARCHAR(10)
  , NR INT
)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('1',101),('1',102),('1',103),('1',105)
      ,('1-2',106),('1-2',109), ('1-2',110)
      ,('2',201),('2',202)
      ,('3',300),('3',350),('3',351),('3',352)

SELECT * FROM @T

;WITH GROUPNUMS (RN, GRP, NR, NRS) AS 
(
    SELECT 1, GRP, MIN(NR), CAST(MIN(NR) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY GRP

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CT.RN + 1, T.GRP, T.NR, CT.NRS + ', ' + CAST(T.NR AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @T T
    INNER JOIN GROUPNUMS CT ON CT.GRP = T.GRP 
    WHERE T.NR > CT.NR
)
SELECT NRS.GRP, NRS.NRS
FROM GROUPNUMS NRS
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT GRP, MAX(RN) AS MRN 
    FROM GROUPNUMS 
    GROUP BY GRP
) R
ON NRS.RN = R.MRN AND NRS.GRP = R.GRP
ORDER BY NRS.GRP
```

Can anyone tell me if it's easily possible to do something like that?
Would be great if anyone has an idea and would like to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my try:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , GRP VARCHAR(10)
  , NR INT
)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES ('1',101),('1',102),('1',103),('1',105)
      ,('1-2',106),('1-2',109), ('1-2',110)
      ,('2',201),('2',202)
      ,('3',300),('3',350),('3',351),('3',352)

SELECT * FROM @T

;WITH T1 as
(
    SELECT GRP, NR, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by GRP, NR) ID FROM @T
)
,T as (
    SELECT *, 1 CNT FROM T1 where ID=1
    union all
    SELECT b.*, (case when T.NR+1=b.NR and T.GRP=b.GRP then t.CNT 
                        else T.CNT+1 end)
    from T1 b INNER JOIN T on b.ID=T.ID+1
)
, TN as(
    select *, 
        MIN(NR) over(partition by GRP, CNT) MinVal, 
        MAX(NR) over(partition by GRP, CNT) MaxVal
    From T
)
SELECT GRP, STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ','+(CASE WHEN MinVal=MaxVal THEN CAST(MinVal as nvarchar(10)) ELSE CAST(MinVal as nvarchar(10))+'-'+cast(MaxVal as nvarchar(10)) END)
       FROM TN b where b.GRP=a.GRP
        FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [ACCOUNT NAMES]
FROM TN a GROUP BY GRP
```

Comment: your query fails to give the expected result on this test data ('3',300),('3',350),('3',351),('3',353),('3',352)

Comment: Yes, U r correct, I just wanted to show a different approach to given question. This can be attained with `ROW_NUMBER()` and an extra block.

Comment: +1 for giving a solution which is - imho - a bit more easier to read. I just like this approach. If you edit your post to include the fix I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I prefer the other solution, it avoids recursion making it perform faster and will not fail at 100 recursions (this part is easy to fix)

Answer (score 6):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fa8c/29)

```
with TRes 
as 
(
select T.GRP,T.NR NR,
CASE WHEN T1.NR IS NULL and T2.NR is null
      THEN CAST(T.NR as VARCHAR(MAX))
     WHEN T1.NR IS NULL and T2.NR IS NOT NULL
      THEN '-'+CAST(T.NR as VARCHAR(MAX))
     WHEN T1.NR IS NOT NULL and T2.NR IS NULL
      THEN CAST(T.NR as VARCHAR(MAX))+'-'
END AS NR_GRP


from T
left join T T1 on T.Grp=T1.Grp and t.Nr+1=t1.Nr
left join T T2 on T.Grp=T2.Grp and t.Nr-1=t2.Nr

WHERE T1.NR IS NULL or T2.NR IS NULL

)
SELECT
   GRP,
   REPLACE(
   substring((SELECT ( ',' + NR_GRP)
                           FROM TRes t2
                           WHERE t1.GRP = t2.GRP
                           ORDER BY 
                              GRP,
                              NR
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 2, 10000 )
   ,'-,-','-')  
FROM TRes t1
GROUP BY GRP
```